# Selecting the range of zip code boundries in R from big data set

Tags: r, plot, zipcode

I could not find the zip code boundaries file of certain city or state. I downloaded a big zip code file from us [census](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html)  and tried to separate the zip code boundaries of Florida with the following R code:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

gpclibPermit()

zip <- readShapeSpatial("~/data/cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k.shp")

zip$GEOID10 <- as.integer(zip$GEOID10)

bool_fl <- 32000 < zip$GEOID10 & zip$GEOID10 <34999

zip1 <-subset(zip, bool_fl)

plot(zip1)
```

The problem I have is , when I change `zip$GEOID10 to integer`,  corresponding index values are changed randomly and I get random map. Do you have any idea how to separate a specific rage of zip code data from large data.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `zipcode` package to help here:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(zipcode)

data(zipcode)

zip <- readShapeSpatial("cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k/cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k.shp")
fl <- zip[zip$GEOID10 %in% zipcode[zipcode$state=="FL",]$zip,]
plot(fl)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for very nice example

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct; the only thing you need to take into account is that `zip$GEOID10` is factor, so you need to convert it to a character vector first:

```
zip$GEOID10 <- as.integer(as.character(zip$GEOID10))
```